# Statsmodels gives different ANOVA results to SPSS

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, statsmodels

I'm getting acquainted with Statsmodels so as to shift my more complicated stats completely over to python. However, I'm being cautious, so I'm cross-checking my results with SPSS, just to make sure I'm not making any obvious blunders. Most of time, there's no difference, but I have one example of a two-way ANOVA that's throwing up very different test statistics in Statsmodels and SPSS. (Relevant point: the sample sizes in the ANOVA are mismatched, so ANOVA may not be the appropriate model here.)

I'm selecting my model as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import seaborn as sns
import statsmodels
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Body = pd.read_csv(filepath)

Body = Body.dropna()

Body_lm = ols('Effect ~ C(Fiction) + C(Condition) + C(Fiction)*C(Condition)', data = Body).fit()

table = sm.stats.anova_lm(Body_lm, typ=2)
```

The Statsmodels output is as below:

```
                            sum_sq     df           F        PR(>F)
C(Fiction)               278.176684    1.0  307.624463  1.682042e-55
C(Condition)               4.294764    1.0    4.749408  2.971278e-02
C(Fiction):C(Condition)   10.776312    1.0   11.917092  5.970123e-04
Residual                 520.861599  576.0         NaN           NaN
```

The corresponding SPSS results are these:

[image: SPSS]

Can anyone help explain the difference? Is is perhaps the unequal sample sizes being treated differently under the hood? Or am I choosing the wrong model?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: It looks like you are using type 2 ANOVA in statsmodels and type 3 in SPSS. Try using also type 3 Anova in statsmodels. Note, in balanced datasets with orthogonal design the types of ANOVA all give the same results, but not in designs that are not orthogonal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried changing this, but had no joy: the results stayed different. Also tried dropping nan values before passing the dataframe to both statsmodels and SPSS––still no joy!

Comment: I have bumped into exactly the same issue, on a different example coming from my own dataset, almost a year later - I don't suppose you have found out the cause? It's making me a little nervous to have very different values from SPSS

Comment: No, I'm afraid I never did get to the bottom of this problem! Post back if you do ...

Answer (score 0):

You should use [sum coding](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/contrasts.html) when comparing the means of the variables.
BTW you don't need to specify each variable that are in the interaction term if `*` [multiply operator](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formulas.html) is used:

“:” adds a new column to the design matrix with the product of the other two columns.
“*” will also include the individual columns that were multiplied together.

Your model should be:

```
Body_lm = ols('Effect ~ C(Fiction, Sum)*C(Condition, Sum)', data = Body).fit()
```