# 2-way ANOVA in Python statsmodels yields different Sum of Squares than SPSS

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, statsmodels, anova

I am learning to use Python for my statistical analyses, and while figuring out how to perform a 2-way ANOVA with statsmodels I found that my Python code yielded slightly aberrant values. Comparing the outputs you can see that the SS_Factor_1 values, and the Adjusted R2 are different for Python vs SPSS/Graphpad. Moreover, although SPSS and Graphpad calculate Type III Sum of Squares, the statsmodel ANOVA output when typ=3 is the most aberrant, whereas typ=1 or 2 are much closer. Why do they disagree? And why is the typ=3 the most different?

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42160020/statsmodels-gives-different-anova-results-to-spss), which was unanswered. My reputation is also too low to comment on that question.

**Type II Sum of Squares Python code:**

```
formula = 'dependent_variable ~ C(factor_1) * C(factor_2)'
model = ols(formula, data=df_freq_time).fit()
aov_table = anova_lm(model, typ=2)
aov_table
```

**Python output:**
[image: output]

**Type III Sum of Squares Python code:**

```
formula = 'dependent_variable ~ C(factor_1) * C(factor_2)'
model = ols(formula, data=df_freq_time).fit()
aov_table = anova_lm(model, typ=3)
aov_table
```

**Python output:**
[image: output]

Also R2 = 0.722, and adj R2 = 0.694 for the above ANOVAs.

**SPSS 2-way ANOVA results:**
[image: SPSS output ANOVA table]

**Graphpad Prism 2-way ANOVA results:**
[image: Graphpad output ANOVA table]

Comment: The SSQ also doesn't match a manual calculation in python. So it seems like the statsmodel library uses a different calculation? Any idea why this is?